# Excel UDF IF Statement <> String Raises #Value Error

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, vba

Hello I am working on a larger Excel UDF apart of it is comparing two different strings to see if they are not equal. When I check to see if the cell in my range is not equal to my desired string ("red" in this example) then add a value which is one row to the right to the counter. When I do this it raises a #value error.

It is interesting though that if I do the same thing but only add values that are equal to "Red" it doesn't raise an error.

```
Function SUM_IF_NOT_RED(Creiteria_Rnage As Range, Sum_range As Integer) as Double

Dim counter As Double
Dim Cell As Range

For Each Cell In Creiteria_Rnage .Cells

If (Cell.Value <> "Red") Then
    counter = counter + Cell.Offset(0, Sum_range).Value
End If

Next Cell

SUM_IF_NOT_RED = counter
End Function
```

I know I can do sum(range) - sumif("Red",range) to get the answer but I'm curious why this UDF raises an error when you set it to <> but works fine when its set to =.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function input parameter are variant. I have also included a parameter col which should be integer and its the difference between the criteria column and the column from where we want to pick the data.

```
Function SUM_IF_NOT_RED(Creiteria_Range, col) As Double

    Dim counter As Double
    Dim Cell As Range

    For Each Cell In Creiteria_Range.Cells

        If (Cell.Value <> "Red") Then
            counter = counter + Cell.Offset(0, col)
        End If

    Next Cell

    SUM_IF_NOT_RED = counter
End Function
```

[image]